# Can I use JNI in a Java Applet?

Tags: java, applet, java-native-interface

Is it possible to use JNI (Java Native Interface) in Applets, has anyone has tried?

Comment: Yes, it is. What's your problem? The security manager?

Comment: was not sure i wanted to try JNI in an applet thnks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JNI from an applet, just remember that the applet is running on the client so JNI will be accessing the client for the "NI" part.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite good in JNI but I googled link which can help you. It contains info about accessing DLL with JNI. Take a look:
[Calling a DLL from an Applet via JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713403/calling-a-dll-from-an-applet-via-jni)